# Relationship between ${}_3F_2$ hypergeometric functions

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, hypergeometric-function

The ${}_3F_2$ hypergeometric function is defined as:
$$ {}_3F_2(1,a,b;c,d;z)=\dfrac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(d)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma(a+n)\Gamma(b+n)}{\Gamma(c+n)\Gamma(d+n)}z^n,$$
for $a,b,c,d,z\in\mathbb{C}$. Note that the above series is absolutely convergent if $|z|<1$.

Then, I am trying to look for a relationship between this two ${}_3F_2$:
$${}_3F_2(1,a,b;c,d;z)$$
and
$${}_3F_2(1,a+1/2,b+1/2;c+1/2,d+1/2;z),$$
where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|<1$.

On the one hand, I search in the literature (for example, in 'Higher Trascendental Functions' of Bateman or 'Generalized Hypergeometric Functions' of Slater). On the other hand, I also try to use the relationship between $\Gamma(z)$ and $\Gamma(z+1/2)$, but I am not be capable of doing, so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What makes you think there is *that general* relation?